# Element Property Inheritance & Re-Use XAML Better Practices

Tags: xaml

Is there way to define a combination of properties that can be added to items?

so instead of:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hi" Foreground="Gray" Margin="0,8,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
<TextBlock Text="there" Foreground="Gray" Margin="0,8,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
```

I would do something like

```
<PropertyCombo name="textBlockCombo1" 
    Foreground="Gray" Margin="0,8,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
.
.
.
<TextBlock Text="Hi" ImportProperty="textBlockCombo1"/>
<TextBlock Text="there" ImportProperty="textBlockCombo1"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, which really makes maintenance and readability so much easier....

Just do something like this either at the parent instance level, or even higher up the tree for inheritance down like from the DOM.

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,10"/>
         <Setter Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
      </Style>
   </StackPanel.Resources/>

   <TextBlock/>
   <TextBlock/>
   <TextBlock/>
   <TextBlock/>
   <TextBlock/>

</StackPanel>
```

You can also just make x:Key static styles and throw them in a resource dictionary and call them where needed like at the instance;

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="AwesomeStyleName">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,10"/>
   <Setter Property="Text" Value="Blah"/>
</Style>
```

Then invoke at instance;

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource AwesomeStyleName}"/>
```

Or apply the same to a group in an instance like;

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource AwesomeStyleName}"/>
   </StackPanel.Resources/>

    <TextBlock/>
    <TextBlock/>
    <TextBlock/>

</StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Any time, have a great weekend!